# python reference a property like a function

Tags: python, list, properties, reference, setter

How do you pythonically set multiple properties without referencing them individually? Below is my solution.

```
class Some_Class(object):

    def __init__(self):
        def init_property1(value): self.prop1 = value
        def init_property2(value): self.prop2 = value

        self.func_list = [init_property1, init_property2]

    @property
    def prop1(self):
        return 'hey im the first property'

    @prop1.setter
    def prop1(self, value):
        print value

    @property
    def prop2(self):
        return 'hey im the second property'

    @prop2.setter
    def prop2(self, value):
        print value


class Some_Other_Class(object):

    def __init__(self):

        myvalues = ['1 was set by a nested func','2 was set by a nested func']
        some_class= Some_Class()

        # now I simply set the properties without dealing with them individually
        # this assumes I know how they are ordered (in the list)
        # if necessary, I could use a map

        for idx, func in enumerate(some_class.func_list):
            func(myvalues[idx])

        some_class.prop1 = 'actually i want to change the first property later on'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Some_Other_Class()
```

this became necessary to do when I had many many properties to initialize with user defined values. My code otherwise would look like a giant list of setting each property individually (very messy).

Note that many people have good answers below and I think I have reached a good solution. This is a re-edit mostly trying to clearly state the question. But, if anyone has a better approach please share!

Comment: You can't ensure read-only access for a class's variables in Python. You can only _discourage_ access to those variables.

Comment: What is `self.setter1` doing? If you're in a class declaration then `self` won't be an instance of your class.  Can you make it clearer where this code is and what `self` is in this context.

Comment: Also, you don't have any properties in your code.

Comment: @JoelCornett with name mangling it is pretty strongly discouraged...although since it uses some reasonable rules to mangle you can indeed still access

Comment: Your question still isn't really clear.  What do you mean by "access these functions separately later on in the code"?  Where in your example is "later"?  Please post an example of what you want to do.

Comment: -1 For having a question so garbled that you have complained about every answer. Take a look at: http://sscce.org/ and http://whathaveyoutried.com/ (useful, even though you have some code).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I updated my question. anymore feedback let me know.

Answer (score 2):

just use the @property decorator

```
>>> class A:
...    a=2
...    @property
...    def my_val(self,val=None):
...        if val == None:return self.a
...        self.a = val
...
>>> a=A()
>>> a.my_val
2
>>> a.my_val=7
>>> a.my_val
7
```

something like this?

if you only want to allow setting then dont give it a default val

```
>>> class A:
...    a=2
...    @property
...    def my_val(self,val):
...        self.a = val
...
>>> a=A()
>>> a.my_val
<Exception>
>>> a.my_val=7
>>> a.a
7
```

or if you only want to allow retrieval just ommit the 2nd arg

```
>>> class A:
...    a=2
...    @property
...    def my_val(self):
...        return self.a
...      
...
>>> a=A()
>>> a.my_val
2
>>> a.my_val=7
<Exception>
```

Comment: In >= 2.6 - after `@property ... def my_val ...` you can then do `@my_val.setter ... def my_val(self, val)...` so you don't need the defaulted parameter and second arg in the first codeblock.

Comment: good addition ... I think i had used that before ... but usually the default arg is elegant enough for my purposes

Comment: The problem isn't how to implement properties for basic retrieval. Take your example: now I want to store "a" in a list, g, and then do g[index_of_a] = 5 and have it update the property. Unfortunately, given your approach the value of the property gets stored in the list - not the properties setter method.

Comment: yes, and I cant answer my own question cause im a newbie... But I got it to work. Here is what I did: Create a small function that simply calls the property set method: def setprop1(value): self.prop = value. Now that function (and there is one for each property) can be referenced in a list. And if you make it a nested function inside of a function that sets all the properties you never have to see it again! If someone has a more elegant solution to that let me know! I will post my answer tomorrow (when I am able to).

Answer (score 2):

I ... finally think I know what you're trying to do, and you don't need to do it the way you're approaching it.  Let me take a stab at this.

```
class someclass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        func_list = [self.setter1, self.setter2]
        value_list = [1, 2]
        #    These lines don't need to be this complicated.
        #    for ind in range(len(func_list)): 
        #        func_list[ind](value_list[ind])

        for idx, func in enumerate(func_list):
            func(value_list[idx])

        #  Or even better
        for idx, (func, val) in enumerate(zip(func_list, value_list)):
            func(val)

    def setter1(self, value): 
        self.a = value

    def setter2(self, value): 
        self.b = value
```

It's worth pointing out that the idx variable and enumerate calls are superfluous in the second form, but I wasn't sure if you need that elsewhere.

Comment: close - but I am trying to use properties. see my answer

Comment: Thank you for the insight on enumeration though - part of your answer will be in mine!

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the property in the object dict, you will get the property descriptor (if any), and likewise with the class; e.g.

```
a = SomeClass()
descriptor = a.__dict__.get('descriptor', type(a).__dict__.get('descriptor'))
```

Assuming that `descriptor` is a descriptor, it will have the following methods:

```
['deleter', 'fdel', 'fget', 'fset', 'getter', 'setter']
```

Note the `fget` and `fset`.

Comment: im sure this works but honestly code like this is way too hard on my brain. I plead ignorance!

Comment: What exactly is difficult for you about this? It has one function call nested inside another.

Comment: well, seeing how you could use this for accessing the property setter method would be nice. Otherwise it is not intuitive - see my answer below

Comment: @ecr I've added a list of the methods on descriptors in case you can't look that up.

Comment: @ecr I still have no idea what you want to do. The above shows you how to get a property descriptor. A list isn't an executable piece of code.

Comment: @ecr I found your example less than illuminating when it was in your question. It's not even there now.

Comment: yes, read the question. It references the example in my answer (the one answered Jul 26 at 18:59).

Comment: @ecr That's a terrible way to ask a question.

Comment: @ecr How about you follow normal practice for asking questions, which is to say, write concisely, and use code examples, together with samples of input and output (whether real, or simulated), rather than challenging people to understand your question.

Comment: ok, I tried my best to re-write the question. I think it was too wordy before also so I lightened it. Is it clear now? Thanks for your feedback.